# Blazor - Navigate to razor page from Controller

Tags: c#, .net, api, blazor

I am using Blazor and I have an instance where I need to redirect the user to an external site which I pass them a url to return to.

The url they return to, they want to POST the data back into my application so I have created an `ApiController` in the blazor application and the data is coming back into there fine, but is there a way I can now use the `NavigationManager` or something like that to redirect the user?

NOTE: Blazor doesn't handle POST Requests to `.razor` pages, only GET, hence why I have to implement the `ApiController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LocalRedirect`:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
  puplic IActionResult GotToSomePage(string redirectUri)
  {
    //Your code
    return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I decided that I was going open the external page in an iframe so when they post back to my endpoint, im still in my web application. And set up a timer that refreshes the state every 5 seconds and checks the database which my api will update when the request is complete :D