# Open/Navigate a Razor component from a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently working on a Blazor server app, and it has a controller in it from a different MVC app, that the client is insisting is moved into the Blazor server app.

The controller currently does the traditional return view, as it was from a different MVC applciation.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction
{
    DoSomeStuff();
    
    return View("ViewName", SomeModel) ;
}
```

However I want to be able to navigate to a razor component such as MyPage.razor (**not** .cshtml page) that is like the following:

```
@page "/MyPage"

    -- Page Content --
    -- Some Razor components --

@code{

    [Parameter] public SomeModel MyModel {get;set;}
    [Parameter] public int MyInt{get;set;}

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
          //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

I want to navigate to this page, from the controller and pass the parameters.

I have tried numerous things, such as RedirecToPage, etc. but it fails, saying it cannot find the page and the message states: The view 'MyPage' was not found. The following locations were searched. All of the locations are showing .cshtml in them, for the location searched etc.

Question 1: Can I navigate to a razor page (SomePage.razor) from a controller.

Question 2: If not, what is the best solution to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor - Navigate to razor page from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541744/blazor-navigate-to-razor-page-from-controller)

Comment: The navigation worked, but I can't pass parameters.

Comment: Yes you can pass a parameter but unfortunately  just sample parameter `Built-in types`, please tell me if that is ok for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `return Redirect("/MyPage");` in your controller.

Comment: RedirectTo is not recognised, there is RedirectToPage, but that also fails.

Comment: Edited to working solution.